# Connect iphone with 2 Low Energy devices

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Well, here is my question. I know, that it is possible to connect an iphone to Bluetooth Low Energy device (e.g. Polar Heart Rate Belt), and then deal with the data provided by this non-iOS device in my app. But is it possible to simultaneously connect my iphone with 2 belts? So i could work with the data provided form each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discover and connect to all HR belt devices. You can also use `retrieveConnectedPeripherals` in iOS7. Then sign up for notification for the Heart Rate value characteristic on each peripheral:

```
[currentPeripheral setNotifyValue:notify 
    forCharacteristic:self.heartRateCaracterisctic];
```

Your deleagate will receive a CBPeripheral instance when `didUpdateNotification` fires - use that to figure out which one of the peripherals sent new value:

```
(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral 
    didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic 
    error:(NSError *)error
```

Comment: Well, so u can retrieve data from both devices. I will try your code later, ty =)